# Reading PHP array

Tags: php

I thought to access the value of '1' here, I would need to the following

```
$data['category'][0];

["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

But it doesn't return anything. How would I access the string(1) section to get the value 1?

Here is the full var dump of the variable $data array

```
array(18) { ["RET"]=> string(65) "/account/add-submission" ["URI"]=> string(22) "account/add-submission" ["XID"]=> string(40) "3ee1766dfdbe4684831021c99a9197beaede03be" ["return_url"]=> string(36) "account/submission-complete/ENTRY_ID" ["channel_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["entry_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["ACT"]=> string(1) "4" ["meta"]=> string(556) "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" ["return"]=> string(36) "account/submission-complete/ENTRY_ID" ["site_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["submission_file_hidden_file"]=> string(0) "" ["submission_file_hidden_dir"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(3) "1.1" ["snap_FxlgTgCET"]=> string(13) "vyHdSjitmEUoV" ["submission_file"]=> string(37) "{filedir_1}Tharp_BIO_Pic300x20038.jpg" ["field_id_48"]=> string(37) "{filedir_1}Tharp_BIO_Pic300x20038.jpg" ["field_ft_48"]=> string(4) "none" ["revision_post"]=> array(26) { ["RET"]=> string(65) "/account/add-submission" ["URI"]=> string(22) "account/add-submission" ["XID"]=> string(40) "3ee1766dfdbe4684831021c99a9197beaede03be" ["return_url"]=> string(36) "account/submission-complete/ENTRY_ID" ["author_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["channel_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["entry_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["ACT"]=> string(1) "4" ["meta"]=> string(556) "pdKeUQVJTA6FeLnmeqtK0gGu2C1S2gKOvRrMDjjKMou7JAp2HVA48Gn+yXTjY4tKuBam5rlyszhe3rEF2eClOB5bRPEJ8NYeh/qPBSkDuhuk0j+XYrQ0R7dJhaHZPIr1b5sge8/kqmWj2qvrpO5pE/iC6X4scIO2HmOPjWb4Sea2VgGwgQ70j7Qr1QmHlQAIZ95DXMp3YkietUWLWaFKvr8XwSx+vUhKEaueVoAbP0Le3fu0rMqz2LuZIScGpwn4yPJbenkc0P5ME/nM9CsfnzYPmM1cwTHO1Xe/wtJ3HGbNcglfn+A9ubz1GBNULgUvxYAW6eFrhqfAJ2omfiwSzpQkISJaDZvZofjOCHjiS7VaUIDgWOrznOm7oWR3m5Ut4TOxmsX2jeKpUAvLJQppc1+1hormnRSA0mambV0uodflDaZEZbPKmjWxsZD3doNJzmIG29bQtBV+UWdQ4xkxyM6fhyMmUkKGAgE+Xegkp/zK7+AXc4s8bEBENPAa1UbCkh0XEq4IYIqWRzYL/T2bfyySCPzvrbFBErIwj3jUF+w=" ["return"]=> string(36) "account/submission-complete/ENTRY_ID" ["site_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(3) "asd" ["submission_file_hidden_file"]=> string(0) "" ["submission_file_hidden_dir"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(3) "1.1" ["category"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["snap_FxlgTgCET"]=> string(13) "vyHdSjitmEUoV" ["submission_file"]=> string(24) "Tharp_BIO_Pic300x200.jpg" ["field_id_48_hidden_file"]=> string(0) "" ["field_id_48_hidden_dir"]=> string(1) "1" ["field_id_48"]=> string(24) "Tharp_BIO_Pic300x200.jpg" ["field_ft_48"]=> string(4) "none" ["allow_comments"]=> string(1) "y" ["entry_date"]=> string(10) "1380114180" ["status"]=> string(4) "open" ["previous_status"]=> bool(false) } }
```

Comment: Could you show whole array? I.e. results of `print_r($array);` ?

Answer (score 1):

To access that data you have to use `$data['revision_post']['category'][0]` because `category` array is in `revision_post` array.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$data['category'][0]` is an array.  So you would access like this:

```
$data['category'][0] = array('1');

echo $data['category'][0][0];
```

Try it for yourself by copying and pasting here http://writecodeonline.com/php/